# How to prevent d3 lineRadial lines from connecting?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I am a beginner at d3 and I'm creating a chart with 3 lines: lineMax, lineMin, and linePreci on a radial chart as pictured:
[image: radial chart]

And I have a slider that filters the dates by the month that are shown in the graph. The graph shows up correctly before any filtering, but when the slider is moved then the lines connect back to each other.

Here is an example of my line generator:

```
// Line Generators:

var lineMax = d3.lineRadial()
    .angle(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .radius(function(d) { return y(d.max_temp); })
    .curve(d3.curveLinear);
```

And here is how they are plotted:

```
var linePlotMax = d3.selectAll('.radial').append("path")
        .datum(filteredDate)
        .attr("fill", "none")  // Change fill to none to only draw the line
        .attr("stroke", "#000000")  // Choose a color for the max temperature line
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .attr('z-index', 200)
        .attr("d", lineMax);
```

And here is how my data if filtered, with range1 being the left slider input and range2 being the right slider input:

```
var filteredDate = data.filter(function(d){
        return d.date.getMonth() >= range1 && d.date.getMonth() <= range2;
    });
```

I am trying to get rid of the connection between the first and last data points. I tried using `.curve(d3.curveLinear);` , as well as `.defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.max_temp); });` on the line generator. I also tried `.attr("d", lineMax.defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.max_temp); }));` on the lineplot and it still had no change.

Comment: Is your data sorted correctly?

Comment: @Mark I think so, I printed out the data into console.log() and the correct data is filtered out. I have updated my post to include my data filter

Comment: if you have always your problem, could you put your code in fiddle or in snppet to test it will be easier to help you